# A bit confused with creating custom content parts and placement

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to create a Custom Part that just drops text into the page.  I've created a part using the GUI that I called "Side Feature" and I added a text field called "Featured".   I am trying put it on the side bar which I created on my layout, but I don't know how to move it to the sidebar.  It shows up on my main content.

How do I move it to the sidebar?  I tried using "@Display(Model.Featured)", but that doesn't seem to work.  I also read about the placement.info file, but I'm not too sure how that would work in this sense.

I couldn't find a tutorial/blog post online similar to this.  Most of them were too advanced.  I am very new to Orchard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't without code or additional module: sidebar is a zone for widgets, not for content parts. Placement info only works for local zones within the global Content zone.

If you want to do it through code, follow this: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/26/dispatching-orchard-shapes-to-arbitrary-zones.aspx

If you want to use a module, look for Origami on the gallery.

Comment: Can widgets be different from page to page?  I want to define different side bars for different pages.

Comment: Of course, that's what layers are for. This is explained here:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets#AddingaLayer

Comment: Does this solution still work in the current version 1.4 of Orchard? I've got the `var siteSettings = _siteService.GetSiteSettings();` in place, but don't understand how you can get the zones from it. Downloading the sources doesn't help me understanding how the convert (.As<T>) works, because I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` in my own `ContentPart`.

Comment: This sounds like a completely different question. Yes, this still works in 1.4 but it seems like you are confused about at least a couple of things. I would recommend posting a full question with more details on orchard.codeplex.com/discussions.